# Why can't I assign a parent class to a variable of subclass type?

Tags: java, oop, run-time-polymorphism

Why reference variable of child class can't point to object of parent? i.e

```
Child obj = new Parent();
```

However we can do vice versa
Kindly answer with memory view (heap)

Comment: This is nothing to do with memory.

Comment: There is a hierarchical relationship between object types. Every `Dog` is an `Animal`, but not every `Animal` is a `Dog`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason which has something to do with the memory. It's much more simple. A subclass can extend the behaviour of its superclass by adding new methods. While it is not given, that a superclass has all the methods of its subclasses. Take the following example:

```
public class Parent {
    public void parentMethod() {}
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public void childMethod() {}
}
```

Now let's think about what would happen if you could assign an instance of `Parent` to a variable of type `Child`.

```
Child c = new Parent(); //compiler error
```

Since `c` is of type `Child`, it is allowed to invoke the method `childMethod()`. But since it's really a `Parent` instance, which does not have this method, this would cause either compiler or runtime problems (depending on when the check is done).

The other way round is no problem, since you can't *remove* methods by extending a class.

```
Parent p = new Child(); //allowed
```

`Child` is a subclass of `Parent` and thus inherits the `parentMethod()`. So you can invoke this method savely.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is too late.

I believe we can explain it in terms of memory. Maybe I'm wrong but this is what I'm thinking about this scenario.

```
// Assume, Required 2KB for execution
public class Parent {
    public void display(){      
        System.out.println("From Parent");
    }
}

// Total memory required for execution : 4bk
public class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    public void display() {     
        super.display(); // 2KB
    }
    
    public void sayHello() {     
        System.out.println("From Child - Hello"); // 2KB
    }
}



   //2KB expect    //4KB assigned
     Parent parent = new Child();
        
   //4KB expect    //Only 2KB is assigning
     Child child = new Parent();
```

Here the 'CHILD' class variable is expecting 4KB memory, but we are trying to assign 2KB 'Parent' class objects to it. So the compiler throwing exception.