# Why i cant assign my super class object to extended class?

Tags: java

Why i cant assign my super class object to base class

```
class Alpha {
    String getType() {
        return "alpha";
    }
}

class Beta extends Alpha {
    String getType() {
        return "beta";
    }
}


public class Gamma extends Beta {
    String getType() {
        return "gamma";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gamma g1 = new Alpha();
        Gamma g2 = new Beta();
        System.out.println(g1.getType() + " "
         + g2.getType());
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me the reason why it is not possible.

Comment: All apples are fruits but not every fruit is an apple.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43296084/why-cant-i-assign-a-parent-class-to-a-variable-of-subclass-type/43296186#43296186

Comment: i know i cant assign that way... i wanted to know the reason why i cant do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I assign a parent class to a variable of subclass type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43296084/why-cant-i-assign-a-parent-class-to-a-variable-of-subclass-type)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to assign a child class to a parent class. Which is exactly the opposite of what you should be doing.

Imagine you've got classes:

```
public class Mammal {
}

public class Dog extends Mammal {
}

public class Cat extends Mammal {
}
```

Do you think it would be logical to assign:

```
Cat cat = new Mammal();
```

Is any `Mammal` a `Cat`?

Answer (score 1):

No. A reference to a subclass must refer to an instance of itself or one of its subclasses (or null). Because it will not behave correctly.

What sense does the following program make ?

```
Object o = new Object();
String s = (string) o;
int i = s.length();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add cast to compile code:

```
package com.stackoverflow.main;

class Alpha {
    String getType() {
        return "alpha";
    }
}

class Beta extends Alpha {
    String getType() {
        return "beta";
    }
}

public class Gamma extends Beta {
    String getType() {
        return "gamma";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gamma g1 = (Gamma) new Alpha();
        Gamma g2 = (Gamma) new Beta();
        System.out.println(g1.getType() + " " + g2.getType());
    }
}
```

but it will give you exception at runtime

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.stackoverflow.main.Alpha cannot be cast to com.stackoverflow.main.Gamma
    at com.stackoverflow.main.Gamma.main(Gamma.java:21)
```

Because in java you can't cast instance of base type to subtype