# how do expose inferred types for extends class in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, extends

I am studying classes extends in kotlin and I came across this error.
Can you please explain to me why this is so:

```
open class Animal
class Zebra: Animal()

fun main() {
    var animal = Zebra()
    animal = Animal()  // Error: Type mismatch
}
```

Comment: `animal` is of type `Zebra` and `Animal` is not `Zebra` (i.e. not a subclass of `Zebra`) that's why you cannot assign `Animal` to `animal`.

Answer (score 6):

Kotlin’s type inference is one of the most popular Kotlin features in
the JVM world. So popular that Java 10 introduced type inference as
well (limited comparing to Kotlin). Though, there are some dangers
in using this feature. Above all, we need to remember that the
inferred type of an assignment is the exact type of the right side,
and not a superclass or interface:

In most cases, this is not a problem. When we have too restrictive
type inferred, we just need to specify it and our problem is solved:

```
open class Animal
class Zebra: Animal()
fun main() {
    var animal: Animal = Zebra()
    animal = Animal()
}
```

Though, there is no such comfort when we don’t control a library
or another module. In such cases, inferred type exposition can be
really dangerous. Let’s see an example.
Let’s say that you have the following interface used to represent
car factories

```
interface CarFactory {
  fun produce(): Car
}
```

There is also a default car used if nothing else was specified:

```
val DEFAULT_CAR: Car = Fiat126P()
```

Now, all your factories can only produce Fiat126P . Not good. If
you defined this interface yourself, this problem will be probably
caught soon and easily fixed. Though, if it is a part of the external
API ( Elements (classes, functions, objects) that might be used from some
outer module or some part of our code maintained by different developers.
For instance, in libraries, those are all public and protected classes, func-
tions and object declarations), you might be informed first by angry users.
Except that, the return type is important information when some-
one does not know API well, and so for the sake of readability, we
should make it explicit especially in parts of our API visible from
outside (so exposed API).

Comment: The strict type inference is safer, not more dangerous. Compile errors are safe. Leaving potential runtime errors is dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

The `var animal = Zebra()` is just a syntactic sugar for

```
var animal:Zebra = Zebra()
```

this should be clear.

Then the question why we cannot assign super class? **Because methods are being called on objects not references**. If in the future the `Zebra` class will have method `fun roar()` the compiler would not be able to ensure that the `animal` variable will be able to execute such if it would allow to assign there something else that declared type or **subclass** of this type

Read more:

- [Why can't I assign a parent class to a variable of subclass type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43296084/why-cant-i-assign-a-parent-class-to-a-variable-of-subclass-type)

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin (actually the IDE) infers the type of animal to Zebra:

```
var animal = Zebra()   // animal is of type Zebra
animal = Animal()      // type mismatch since Animal is not a Zebra
```

If you specify the type explicitly to be Animal, then you can assign an Animal on the next line:

```
var animal: Animal = Zebra()   // animal is of type Animal
animal = Animal()              // this works
```